# Input file with different number of items on each line

Tags: c++, ifstream

`file.txt:
Item1 Item2 I t e m 3 
Item2 I t e m 3
Item2 I t e m 3
Item1 Item2 I t e m 3
Item1 Item2 I t e m 3
Item2 I t e m 3`

I think I need to use two lines of code:

```
    file >> Item1;
    file >> Item2;
    getline(file, Item3); //item3 has a lot of spaces
```

Some lines in the input file don't have Item1 so,

```
    file >> Item2;
    getline(file, Item3); //item3 has a lot of spaces
```

How do I check if a line of text in the input file will have 3 items or 2 items and use the correct code accordingly.

Comment: If contents of lines is variable, it's probably best to `std::string line; std::getline(file, line);` i.e. reading the whole line and doing the analysis on the string `line`. This requires a parser (which in this case might be a piece of C++ code processing the string `line` character by character). However, development of any parser must be preceded by definition of a formal language i.e. define rules how exactly which characters shall be interpreted when. An IMHO illustrative form is a [syntax diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram).

Comment: ... Once you have defined the rules, it's mostly easy to write the resp. `if`s, `switch`s, and `for`s to translate that rules into parser code.

Comment: Regarding your sample text: `Item2 I t e m 3`. This could be a line with two items (`Item2`, `I t e m 3`) or with three items (`Item2`, `I`, `t e m 3`) or with three items (`Item2`, `I t`, `e m 3`) or... This is ambiguous and can cause unexpected results. You have somehow to define how this shall be handled. May be interesting: The `bash` (and other shells) uses spaces to separate arguments. If you want to use a space _in_ an argument you have to disable its meta-meaning. This can be done e.g. using quotes (`"arg 1"`) or escaping the space itself by a preceding backslash (`arg\ 1`).